# ShowTypingMiddleware broke my bot when deployed - BotFramework V4

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to use the **ShowTypingMiddleware**, a custom middleware already given by BotFramework (see here: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ShowTypingMiddleware.cs) to send an typing message to my user while the bot is processing his request. I'm using the **BotFramework V4**.

It all works locally, but not when I publish it on Azure's WebChat.

I've followed the example in Microsoft's samples, where they create an adapter that adds the desired middleware to the bot pipeline (the sample I've used is here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/17.multilingual-bot. The custom adapter I'm referring to is **AdapterWithErrorHandler.cs**, and it adds the **TranslationMiddleware** to the pipeline).

Running locally, everything works as planned. The problem is: when I'm publishing it to Azure, the webchat stop working. It throws the following exception:

> 7‎/‎21‎/‎2019‎ ‎1‎:‎07‎:‎33‎ ‎PM There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Unauthorized
>
> ‎7‎/‎21‎/‎2019‎ ‎1‎:‎07‎:‎33‎ ‎PM There was an error sending this message to your bot:
>   HTTP status code Unauthorized

In my **StartUp.cs**'s ConfigureServices, I've injected my custom adapter and my middleware:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
                                ...               

  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

   // Create the credential provider to be used with the Bot Framework Adapter.
   services.AddSingleton<ICredentialProvider, ConfigurationCredentialProvider>();

   // Create the Bot Framework Adapter.
   services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithTypingAndErrorHandler>();

   // Create the bot as a transient. In this case the ASP Controller is expecting an IBot.
   services.AddTransient<IBot, MyBot>();

   services.AddSingleton<ShowTypingMiddleware>();
}
```

My **AdapterWithTypingAndErrorHandler** is as follows:

```cs
public class AdapterWithTypingAndErrorHandler : BotFrameworkHttpAdapter
{
  public AdapterWithTypingAndErrorHandler(
    IConfiguration configuration, 
    ILogger<BotFrameworkHttpAdapter> logger, 
    ShowTypingMiddleware showTypingMiddleware) : base(logger: logger)
    {
       if (showTypingMiddleware == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException($"Could not load '{nameof(showTypingMiddleware)}' in custom adapter.");

       AddAdapterToPipeline(showTypingMiddleware);

       OnTurnError = async (turnContext, exception) =>
       {
          logger.LogError($"Exception caught : {exception.Message}");
          await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Sorry, something went wrong :/");
            };
        }

private void AddAdapterToPipeline(ShowTypingMiddleware showTypingMiddleware)
            => Use(showTypingMiddleware);
    }
```

And I'm using it in my controller:

```cs
public class BotController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter Adapter;
    private readonly IBot Bot;

    public BotController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IBot bot)
    {
       Adapter = adapter;
       Bot = bot;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task PostAsync()
    {
       await Adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, Bot);
    }
}
```

As I said, everything works fine,  locally, but when I publish it, the WebChat throws the Unauthorized exception. If I use the default Adapter (the **BotFrameworkHttpAdapter.cs** one), instead of my customized, it all works fine too.

What should I do?

Comment: Are your `Microsoft App Id` and `Microsoft App Password` application settings set against your Bot as per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#microsoftappid-and-microsoftapppassword)? Can you message your bot at all when it is deployed, or does it throw an error on every message?

Comment: What makes you think the Unauthorized error has anything to do with `ShowTypingMiddleware`?

Comment: Answering:

1. Yes, the Microsoft App Id and App Password are setted in my appSettings;

2. Like I've explained, when I use the default Adapter, not the customized, everything work well. Only when I try to use the customized Adapter (that uses the ShowTypingMiddleware), the error is thrown.

Comment: The adapter is responsible for authentication, so the custom adapter probably doesn't handle that correctly. What happens if you use the custom adapter but remove the `ShowTypingMiddleware` from it?

Comment: Are you still working on this?